# multiclass SVM classifies all the samples to most probable claas

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 3 class,

Class A =  190 samples

Class B =  233 samples

Class C = 133 samples

I am using sklearn multiclass SVM (svm.svc) to solve this classification problem but my test set classifies everything to class B What am I missing? 
I tried changing gamma and C (Penalty parameter C) but that didn't help

```
import sklearn.metrics as sm
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm

data = '/Input/AllData.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(data, names=None)

dataframe = dataframe.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

dataset = dataframe.values


X = dataset[:,0:-1]
Y = dataset[:,-1]

Count1=0
Count2=0
Count3=0

for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    if(Y[i]==2):
        Count2=Count2+1
    elif(Y[i]==1):
        Count1=Count1+1
    else:
        Count3=Count3+1
print np.isnan(X[:]).any(), np.isnan(Y).any()
print Count1,Count2 ,Count3



X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
X, Y, test_size=0.15, random_state=1)


model =svm.SVC(C=0.01, cache_size=700, class_weight='balanced', coef0=0.0,
decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
tol=0.001, verbose=False)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train) 
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
ACC = sm.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred)
print ACC


target_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print(sm.classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

You can find data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QK_l3Wpz9Qb6-F7jMzM1cER1z-FaMDHMGZgDY1Jj2Ac/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Also can you post your data?

Comment: also try to scale the data before running the SVM. We wait for your code and data.

Comment: @sera Code and data uploaded

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam please see my answer and the results that I got. Can you check your sklearn version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this part of your code and the **`Y_pred`** does not classify everything to class B.

Can you check your sklearn version? I am using 0.18.

**Code**

```
import sklearn.metrics as sm
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm

data = 'C:/Users/seral_000/AllData.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(data, names=None)

dataframe = dataframe.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
dataset = dataframe.values

X = dataset[:,0:-1]
Y = dataset[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
X, Y, test_size=0.15, random_state=0)

model = svm.SVC( C                        =   0.01,
                 gamma                    =  'auto',
                 kernel                   =  'linear',
                 degree                   =   3,
                 class_weight             =  'balanced',
                 coef0                    =   0.0,
                 decision_function_shape  =   None,
                 probability              =   False,
                 max_iter                 =  -1,
                 tol                      =   0.001,
                 cache_size               = 700,
                 random_state             =   None,
                 shrinking                =   True,
                 verbose                  =   False
                 )

model.fit(X_train, Y_train) 

Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(Y_pred)

ACC = sm.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred)
print ACC

target_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print(sm.classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

**Result in console:**

```
[ 1.  3.  1.  2.  3.  3.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  3.  2.  3.  3.
  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  3.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  3.  3.  1.
  3.  2.  2.  1.  2.  3.  1.  1.  2.  2.  3.  2.  1.  3.  1.  2.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  3.  3.  2.  3.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  1.  3.  1.  1.  3.  3.  3.  1.  2.  2.  1.]

0.52380952381

                  precision recall    f1-score    N-supports

          A       0.71      0.56      0.63        39
          B       0.39      0.45      0.42        29
          C       0.45      0.56      0.50        16

avg / total       0.55      0.52      0.53        84
```